# jquery dropdown doesnt work?

Tags: jquery

Im writing a new wordpress theme. i added my css html and js code samples. what is the problem ? the dropdown menus dont work. Could anyone help me ?

the css part is :

```
.HeaderContent #MainMenuBg {float:left; margin-top:10px; width:880px; height:30px; overflow:hidden;}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li {display:block;  float:left; list-style-type:none; margin-right:10px; margin-top:7px; padding-right:10px;}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li a {font-family:Tahoma; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff; font-size:11px; text-decoration:none;}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li a:hover {text-decoration:underline; color:#FFE212;}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; border-top: 1px solid white}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li ul li { float: none; display: inline} 
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li ul li a { width: auto; background: #9F1B1B}
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li ul li a:hover { background: #7F1616}
```

The html part is:

```
<div id="MainMenuBg">
            <ul id="MainMenu">
                <li><a href="">Ana sayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Güncel</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Son haber 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Son haber 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Son haber 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Son haber 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Son haber 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Siyaset</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Ekonomi</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Politika</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Kadın</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Magazin</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Otomobil</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

JS part is:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#MainMenu li').hover(
        function () {
            //altmenuler
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //altmenugizle
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);         
        }
    );


});
```

What sould i do it works? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any errors on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually working fine but you are not able to see may be because of the css.
The text color of the menu is `white` in your css and the visibility of menu is hidden. Correct the belwo two css rules it should work fine.

Change

```
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden; 
    border-top: 1px solid white
}
```

to

```
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    display: none;/*Changed to display:none becase slideDown/Up do not manipulate visiblity*/
    border-top: 1px solid white
}
```

Change (This will not be the issue if your page background is not white)

```
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li a {
    font-family:Tahoma; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#ffffff; 
    font-size:11px; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

to

```
.HeaderContent #MainMenu li a {
    font-family:Tahoma; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#0000ff;/*Changed to some other color than white */
    font-size:11px; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7fX6S/)**

Comment: you right i found the solution. It was about the css for the top div.. Top div has overflow:hidden elements ;) now i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selam Fatih, there is only one Dropdown Menü in "Güncel", right?

See this example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/7PGPE/1/ - working fine.. What exactly is the problem?